# No results searching for Google Drive files on mac

Tags: macos, spotlight

I'm moving all my business files to Google Drive but Spotlight gives no results when searching for files. Do I have to setup any remaining settings?

Dropbox is doing fine this task in my system.

[image]

MACOS setup
[image]

I'm looking for files in this folder that is already offline.

[image]

Comment: The Google Drive Preferences are set to Stream files stored on Google Drive servers. Consider switching to Mirror mode to store files locally so they can be indexed by Spotlight and searchable.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, I'm looking for files in a 'FARMACIA 2022' folder, that is already offline. See the third snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the Spotlight index. See the solution here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Answer (score 1):

The folders somebody else shared from their MyDrive with you, are showing up as aliases in your MyDrive, and they point to a certain .shortcut-targets-by-id folder (go to get info on the alias, and read the path, or click onto show original button) which is in your hidden user Library folder. I'm not sure if spotlight follows aliases but it will definitely not search in folders starting with . which are "inivisible" in Finder. Note that in the finder search, by using the plus icon, you can make it show "system files" which will then show matches in your Library folder. You can even make it show invisible files, but it seems that this is different than the . invisibility, it is for files which are invisible attribute set, I guess. Long story short, I could not find a way to make finder search/spotlight find files which are in MyDrive Alias folders.